# In yii need to use yii::app()->user->id in form

Tags: php, yii

I need to use yii::app()->user->id in a form and to save the username in table.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'User'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'User',array('size'=>15,'maxlength'=>15)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'User'); ?>
```

I replaced that with:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'User'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'User','yii::app()->user->id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'User'); ?>
```

but that didn't work so I tried:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'User'); ?>
    <?php echo yii::app()->user->id' ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'User'); ?>
```

Now it is printing the username in form but not stored in db table.  Is there any other suggestion that would help me?

After a long try I found an answer in simple way....posting the code for others.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'User'); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->yii::app()->user->id(array('model'=>$model,'attribute'=>'User','value'->$model->User,)); ?>

<input size="15" maxlength="15" name="User[User]" id="User_user" type="hidden" value="<?php echo yii::app()->user->id ?>"  />   


    <?php echo $form->error($model,'User'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: After a long try i found the answer and its work too posting the code for others need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is better to use

```
yii::app()->user->id
```

in the corresponding controller after form submission.

Comment: i cant understand what you coming to tell.please explain i am new to yii

Comment: what i mean is to get user id (username) in the controller handling the form submission, such that you know who made the submission. Then, you can save all the information into table.